# verbatim text in tables and macros

Tags: macros, verbatim

I have a cheatsheet with a table that looks like

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
$k > 0$    &  \verb+k > 0+    \\
$k \geq 0$ &  \verb+k \geq 0+ \\
$\sum_l$   &  \verb+\sum_l+   \\
%etc
\end{tabular}
```

There is a lot of redundancy here since the argument to `verb` is the same as the first entry of the table. I tried to make a macro to remove the duplication

```
\newcommand\code[1]{$#1$& \verb+#1+\\}
```

but that gives an error. I also tried using detokenize

```
\newcommand\code[1]{$#1$&\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}\\}
```

but that introduces superfluous spaces.
How can I define a macro that produces both the formula and its verbatim code?

Comment: Can we assume that the input is essentially math mode material: no `%` tokens, _etc._?

Comment: @Wright Yes these are just math formulas between $ $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You need to read the argument verbatim, to see the spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\code#1{%
\let\do\@makeother \dospecials
\verbatim@font\@noligs
\@vobeyspaces \frenchspacing 
\catcode`#1\active
\lccode`\~`#1%
\lowercase{\long\def\tmp##1~}{\$##1\$&$\scantokens{##1}$\\}%
\tmp
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\code|k > 0|
\code|k \geq 0|
\code|\sum_l|
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

or to swap the columns is a bit harder:-)

```
\makeatletter
\def\code#1{%
\bgroup
\let\do\@makeother \dospecials
\@vobeyspaces 
\catcode`#1\active
\lccode`\~`#1%
\lowercase{\long\def\tmp##1~}{\egroup$\scantokens{##1}$&%
\verbatim@font\@noligs
\@vobeyspaces\frenchspacing 
\$##1\$\\}%
\tmp
}

\makeatother
```

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes not so novel as it turns out: same as egreg's answer in other question but he just uses an xparse `v` argument (which is same thing, really)

Comment: For one who doesn't speak L3, it qualifies as "novel".  Kind of like "verboten" is a novel term for English speakers.  Who would have guessed?  Those Germans have a different word for everything.

Comment: @stackman updated answer

Comment: oh that's `\verb*` rather than `\verb` I put the `\@vobeyspaces` in the wrong place:-) update coming up...

Comment: @stackman updated